# why we write non-negativity condition on metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

why we write non-negativity condition on metric space?
and we can get it from other conditions.

> Blockquote

Comment: Because the original intuitive notion of distance is such that it cannot be negative. - But you are right: $d(x,y)<0$ would lead to $d(y,x)=d(x,y)<0$ and then $0=d(x,x)\le d(x,y)+d(y,x)<0$ from the other conditions. But we need to make clear that $d$ is a function in the first place and thos domain and codomain need to be specified. Why not specifiy $[0,\infty)$  as codomain instead of $\Bbb R$, say, right there if that is what it ultimately boils down to.